# Why does this function to count characters in a file always return 0?

Tags: python, file-read, charactercount

I have been trying to define a function that gets 2 inputs (a character and a file path) and returns the amount of times the character appears in it. I know there is a shorter way to do this with the `method.count` but I would like to know why this function always returns 0.

```
def lettercount(character , path):
    with open("bear.txt") as myfile:
        counter = [obj for obj in myfile if obj==character]
        return len(counter)
```

Comment: Well, if you print your list `counter` you might notice that it's consisting of complete lines and not individual characters..

Comment: how you are stored the data in the file?  is it one line per character if not it will not work?

Comment: You might want to consider iterating through the file char by char.

Comment: `counter = [char for line in myfile for char in line if char == character]` The outer `for` loop iterates through the lines. The inner `for` loop iterates through each character. `return len(counter)` will be correct now.

Comment: Beside the point, but `path` is unused. You hard-coded `"bear.txt"` instead.

Comment: `str.count` is the method you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over a file (`myfile`), you get lines (`obj`). So `obj==character` will only ever be true if the last line of a file is `character` and there's no trailing newline.

---

To iterate over characters, you can add another loop to your comprehension:

```
c for line in myfile for c in line if c==character
```

Although, you don't actually need to keep the characters themselves since you only need their count. You can use `sum()` like this:

```
count = sum(c==character for line in myfile for c in line)
return count
```